# How to check if a range within a specific column covers a specific value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My question is the inverse of this question:
[How to check if any value of a column is in a range (in between two values) in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156469/how-to-check-if-any-value-of-a-column-is-in-a-range-in-between-two-values-in-p)

Instead of having a value in the column that I am trying to compare to a specific range, I actually have a range in the column and I'm trying to get all the rows from the DataFrame for a specific value.

```
data = {'Reward_Level':['0-4','0-4', '5-10', '5-10', '11-16'],
        'reward' :['1', '2', '3', '4', '10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
value = 2 # want to return all the rows whose range in 'Reward_Level' covers this value
df = df["How do I do this part?"]
# df >> gives me the rows for ['0-4', '1'] and ['0-4', '2']
```

The way I know how to do it is to break out `Reward_Level` into two separate columns and compare against the minimum and then also compare against the maximum, but is there a way to do this without breaking these into new columns?

Answer (score 0):

First create an auxiliary DataFrame with extracted limits of each range:

```
df2 = df.Reward_Level.str.extract(r'(?P<v1>\d+)-(?P<v2>\d+)').astype('int')
```

Because values will be used in numeric comparisons, they must be converted
to *int*.

Then use just a boolean indexing:

```
df[df2.v1.le(value) & df2.v2.ge(value)]
```